# Android Layout - Edit Profile Tinder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to achieve something similar to it:

[image]

However, I'm having a little bit of issues with that.
I'm using a Scrollview > RelativeLayout, and inside of it I'm trying to put the elements on the specific position.
I'm going to use it on a DialogFragment, and in the specific case, I'm only going to use 3 thumbs on the right.

Take a look on what I got until now. (*)

[image]

(*) If someone want to take a look on the code, reply to it!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_brmalls"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_bulk_insert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <!-- The button used to add a new student row of UI controls on the screen -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Fotos"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/destaque"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_background"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture01"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/destaque"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture02"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture01"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture03"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture02"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtIrregularidade"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Teste"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/destaque"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirmar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtIrregularidade"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thank you

Comment: You didn't tell us what's the issue.

Comment: @Tarcisiofl what is problem dude??? you want same as before image??

Comment: Yes, that is it! @Android

Comment: @Tarcisiofl you want only three thumbs at right... so how should it looks??

Comment: @Android Yeah, it will look as the second screen. Only three on the right.